# document.html.className not working in angular2

Tags: html, typescript, dom

Following code works fine when I'm removing a class from body tag.

```
switchTheme(themeCode: string) {
    document.body.className = '';
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add(themeCode);
  }
```

**But I can't remove a class from HTML tag as below.**

```
switchTheme(themeCode: string) {
   document.html.className = '';
   document.querySelector('html').classList.add(themeCode);
}
```

It gives following error in the first line of the function.

**Property 'html' does not exist on type 'Document'.**

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `document` does not have this `html` property.
That's not a typescript issue, it's javascript, try to run this in your console:

```
console.log(document.html);
```

And you'll get `undefined`.

To get a reference to the `html` part of the DOM you need to use the `document.documentElement` property ([the type definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7099), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/documentElement)):

```
console.log(document.documentElement);
```

Comment: So, document.documentElement.className = '' is the solution. Thanks